# Filtering a pyspark dataframe using isin by exclusion

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get all rows within a dataframe where a columns value is not within a list (so filtering by exclusion).

As an example:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1','a'),('2','b'),('3','b'),('4','c'),('5','d')]
,schema=('id','bar'))
```

I get the data frame:

```
+---+---+
| id|bar|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  b|
|  4|  c|
|  5|  d|
+---+---+
```

I only want to exclude rows where bar is ('a' or 'b').

Using an SQL expression string  it would be:

```
df.filter('bar not in ("a","b")').show()
```

Is there a way of doing it without using the string for the SQL expression, or excluding one item at a time?

Edit:

I am likely to have a list, ['a','b'], of the excluded values that I would like to use.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It looks like the ~ gives the functionality that I need, but I am yet to find any appropriate documentation on it.

```
df.filter(~col('bar').isin(['a','b'])).show()



+---+---+
| id|bar|
+---+---+
|  4|  c|
|  5|  d|
+---+---+
```

Comment: It is a default python operator, in folk language called the `not` operator. In the documentation it is called the `unary bitwise invert operator`: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations

Answer (score 36):

Also could be like this

```
df.filter(col('bar').isin(['a','b']) == False).show()
```

Comment: is there any difference between this and using the invert operator (`~`)?

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: In this case I think there is no real difference since `isin` returns either `True` or `False`. However, in general, comparison like `x == False` is discouraged and might yield surprising results.

Answer (score 30):

Got a gotcha for those with their headspace in Pandas and moving to pyspark

```
 from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

 spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MyAppName")
 sc = SparkContext(conf = spark_conf)
 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

 records = [
     {"colour": "red"},
     {"colour": "blue"},
     {"colour": None},
 ]

 pandas_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records)
 pyspark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(records)
```

So if we wanted the rows that are **not** red:

```
pandas_df[~pandas_df["colour"].isin(["red"])]
```

[image: As expected in Pandas]

Looking good, and in our pyspark DataFrame

```
pyspark_df.filter(~pyspark_df["colour"].isin(["red"])).collect()
```

[image: Not what I expected]

So after some digging, I found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20617
So to include **nothingness** in our results:

```
pyspark_df.filter(~pyspark_df["colour"].isin(["red"]) | pyspark_df["colour"].isNull()).show()
```

[image: much ado about nothing]

Comment: A `when` function would probably work here too.

Answer (score 16):

```
df.filter((df.bar != 'a') & (df.bar != 'b'))
```