# Check if values of column pyspark df exist in other column pyspark df

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 pyspark dataframes and I want to check if the values of one column exist in a column in the other dataframe.

I have only seen solutions of how to filter the values that exist ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775281/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-using-isin-by-exclusion)), what I need to do is to return a column of true or false.

In pandas it will be something like this:

```
df_A["column1"].isin(df_B["column1"])
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can collect all the values in column1 and then make a broadcast variable from it, on which you can write a udf

```
from pyspark.sql import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

df_B_col_1_values = df_B.rdd.map(lambda x: x.column1).distinct().collect()
df_B_col_1_values = sc.broadcast(set(df_B_col_1_values))

my_udf = udf(lambda x: x in df_B_col_1_values.value, BooleanType())
df_A = df_A.withColumn('column1_present', my_udf(col('column1'))
```

Comment: What if the dataframe you're trying to broadcast is too large for your cluster ?

Comment: If the DataFrame you are broadcasting is too large, then you can achieve the same result by doing a left_semi join.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** a cleaner way to do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df1.join(df2.withColumn('flag', F.lit(True)), 'col1', 'left').fillna(False)

result.show()
+----+-----+
|col1| flag|
+----+-----+
|   0| true|
|   1| true|
|   2|false|
+----+-----+
```

Old answer:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(([0],[1],[2])).toDF('col1')
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(([0],[1],[3])).toDF('col1')

df1.join(df2, 'col1', 'semi') \
   .distinct() \
   .select('col1', F.lit(True).alias('flag')) \
   .join(df1, 'col1', 'right') \
   .fillna(False, 'flag') \
   .show()

+----+-----+
|col1| flag|
+----+-----+
|   0| true|
|   1| true|
|   2|false|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: This edited response works - the two Dataframes have to have column with the same name (in mck's example, the column is 'col1') and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To tweak Mck's answer a little bit (drop duplicate `df_A` entries and select the relevant columns):

**SHORT**

```py
df_A = df_A.withColumn("uid_A", F.monotonically_increasing_id())  # Add an index column
df_B = df_B.withColumn("uid_B", F.monotonically_increasing_id())  # Add an index column

df_A = df_A.alias('df_A')
(
    df_A
    .join(df_B.withColumn('flag',F.lit(True)),'col1','left')
    .fillna(False)
    .dropDuplicates(['uid_A'])
    .select('df_A.col1','flag')
).show()

'''
+----+-----+
|col1| flag|
+----+-----+
|   A|false|
|   B|false|
|   C| true|
|   B|false|
|   C| true|
|   D| true|
+----+-----+
'''
```

**FULL**

```py
### Initialise dataframe ###

df_A = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                     'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df_A = spark.createDataFrame(df_A)

df_B = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['C', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 
                     'col2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]})
df_A = spark.createDataFrame(df_B)

### PREVIOUS ###

df_A.join(df_B.withColumn('flag',F.lit(True)),'col1','left').fillna(False).show()

'''
+----+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|col2| flag|
+----+----+----+-----+
|   A|   1|null|false|
|   B|   2|null|false|
|   B|   4|null|false|
|   C|   3|  10| true|
|   C|   3|  40| true|
|   C|   5|  10| true|
|   C|   5|  40| true|
|   D|   6|  30| true|
+----+----+----+-----+
'''

### BETTER ###

df_A = df_A.withColumn("uid_A", F.monotonically_increasing_id())  # Add an index column
df_B = df_B.withColumn("uid_B", F.monotonically_increasing_id())  # Add an index column

df_A = df_A.alias('df_A')
(
    df_A
    .join(df_B.withColumn('flag',F.lit(True)),'col1','left')
    .fillna(False)
    .dropDuplicates(['uid_A'])
    .select('df_A.col1','flag')
).show()

'''
+----+-----+
|col1| flag|
+----+-----+
|   A|false|
|   B|false|
|   C| true|
|   B|false|
|   C| true|
|   D| true|
+----+-----+
'''
```

Extra nuggets: To take only column values based on the `True`/`False` values of the `.isin` results, it may be more straightforward to use pyspark's `leftsemi` join which takes only the left table columns based on the matching results of the specified cols on the right, shown also in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547745/10002593).

```py
# Pandas (isin)
df_A["column1"].isin(df_B["column1"])

# Pyspark (isin equivalent, applied to column values)
df_A.join(df_B, ["column1"], "leftsemi").select("column1")

'''
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   C|   3|
|   C|   5|
|   D|   6|
+----+----+
'''

# Pandas (~isin)
df_A["column1"].isin(df_B["column1"])

# Pyspark (~isin equivalent, applied to column values)
df_A.join(df_B, ["column1"], "leftanti").select("column1")
```

Further join examples/info - [PySpark Join Types | Join Two DataFrames](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/#pyspark-left-semi-join)