# I need to compare two files using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, compare

I'm new to PySpark and need to compare two files based on col1 alone  and populate new colum at end of file 1 based on matching conditions.

1 - Matching record
0 - Unmatached Record

**File1**:

| Col1 | Col2 | ... | ColN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | ... | Xxxx |
| 2 | abc | ... | Xxxx |
| 3 | abc | ... | Xxxx |

**File 2**

| Col1 | Col2 | ... | ColN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | ... | Xxxx |
| 2 | abc | ... | Xxxx |

**Expected output:**

| Col1 | Col2 | ... | ColN | Newcol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | ... | Xxxx | 1 |
| 2 | abc | ... | Xxxx | 1 |
| 3 | abc | ... | Xxxx | 0 |

Comment: Learn how `join` works on dataframes. This is really basic question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if values of column pyspark df exist in other column pyspark df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031917/check-if-values-of-column-pyspark-df-exist-in-other-column-pyspark-df)